# Comsuming GeoJSON with JAX-RS

Tags: java, jackson, jax-rs, geojson

I want to be able to consume GeoJSON with a JAX-RS service that uses Jackson for JSON handling. I'm a little baffled by how to handle it correctly. The problem is that parts of GeoJSON can be an array, an array of arrays, or an array of arrays of arrays ... and i dont know how to specify the beans for this situation.

In GeoJSON the geometry structure can have coordinates as an array:

```
{ "type": "Point", "coordinates": [100.0, 0.0] }
```

or an array of arrays:

```
{ "type": "LineString",
    "coordinates": [ [100.0, 0.0], [101.0, 1.0] ]
}
```

or an array of arrays of arrays:

```
{ "type": "Polygon",
   "coordinates": [
   [ [100.0, 0.0], [101.0, 0.0], [101.0, 1.0], [100.0, 1.0], [100.0, 0.0] ]
   ]
}
```

how do i define the pojo for this to go into?

```
public class Geometry {
    public String type;
    public List<Double> coordinates;              // this
    public List<List<Double>> coordinates;        // or this
    public List<List<List<Double>>> coordinates;  // or this?
```

}

Comment: Can you give the url for the GeoJSON API? I think you can define POJO for different geometries i.e. Point, LineString, Polygon.

Comment: http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#appendix-a-geometry-examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ended up creating some beans with jackson annotations. I've put these in google code. the code can be found here: http://code.google.com/p/belteshazzar-geojson/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Fcom%2Fbelteshazzar%2Fgeojson

Comment: This link is broken (404)

Answer (score 2):

> how do i define the pojo for this to go into?

I had the same trouble with modelling the GeoJSON string into POJOs. However I abandoned trying to reinvent the wheel when I bumped into [GeoJSON-POJO](https://github.com/MPriess/GeoJSON-POJO)
, a Simple POJO implementation of GeoJSON Format Specification 1.0.

Works just fine.